# Is it possible to manually authenticate server's credentials in Android application?

Tags: java, android, ios, kotlin, certificate

Coming from the iOS background, it is possible to [Performing Manual Server Trust Authentication](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/handling_an_authentication_challenge/performing_manual_server_trust_authentication?language=objc), i.e. allow the app to authenticate server's credentials. I have looked around, and have not found any information on whenever it is possible to do in Android application (preferably, in Kotlin, but Java is fine too). Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, it is possible and desirable. You need to define a truststore in your application and configure the SSL connection to use it. You have many similar questions in SO. If you do not configure a custom truststore, it is used the Android default truststore

Comment: It's called "certificate pinning". E.g., https://www.netguru.co/codestories/3-ways-how-to-implement-certificate-pinning-on-android. Or Google for other examples.